# Can I trigger the Logic Pro caps lock keyboard without using Caps Lock?

Tags: logic-pro, mac

As a programmer, I don't like to leave Caps Lock enabled on my Mac, because it causes all sorts of unintended errors.

But, as a musician, I use Logic Pro. I want to use its Caps Lock keyboard, but I'd rather not have to re-enable Caps Lock every time. Is there a way to map this to a new key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic Pro does not provide any way to enable the Caps Lock keyboard without using Caps Lock, unfortunately.  However, on the Mac you can hook up multiple keyboards and only disable Caps Lock on your primary one, or you can try an ultra-compact USB-MIDI keyboard such as the Oxygen8 or Korg NanoKEY.

Also, if you just want to sequence a quick riff and don't mind doing that in GarageBand, you can always access GarageBand's "musical typing" mode via cmd-shift-K, and then copy the recorded sequence into Logic.

Answer (score 0):

With Logic Pro 9 there is the Keyboard Commands manager:

- [Saving Time with Logic Pro 9: Keyboard Shortcuts](http://audio.tutsplus.com/tutorials/logic-pro/saving-time-with-logic-pro-9-keyboard-shortcuts/)

I think this will help you.

Comment: Already looked there. Unfortunately there is no entry for toggling the Caps Lock keyboard.